# " Pod is blocking scale down because it has local storage "

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have kubernets cluster in gcp with docker container runtime. I am trying to change docker container runtime into containerd. Following steps shows what I did.

1. New node pool added ( nodes with containerd )
2. drained old nodes

Once I perform above steps I am getting " Pod is blocking scale down because it has local storage " warning message.

Comment: feel free to update the status of question if any of below answer resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the once annotation to POD so that cluster autoscaler can remove that POD from POD safe to evict.

```
cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true"
```

above annotation, you have to add in into POD.

You can read more at : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#cluster-not-scalingdown

> NoScaleDown example: You found a noScaleDown event that contains a
> per-node reason for your node. The message ID is
> "no.scale.down.node.pod.has.local.storage" and there is a single
> parameter: "test-single-pod". After consulting the list of error
> messages, you discover this means that the "Pod is blocking scale down
> because it requests local storage". You consult the Kubernetes Cluster
> Autoscaler FAQ and find out that the solution is to add a
> "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true" annotation to
> the Pod. After applying the annotation, cluster autoscaler scales down
> the cluster correctly.

Comment: What's a local storage in this case?

Comment: @ShinebayarG - an emptyDir volume mount, which usually holds data that is ephemeral

Answer (score 1):

For further clarification, you can use this command to update the pod's annotation:

```
kubectl annotate pod <podname> -n <namespace> "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict=true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error when using Gitlab + Autodevops + GoogleCloud.
The issue is the cm_acme pods's that are spun up to answer the letsencrypt challenges.

e.g. we have pods like this
`cm-acme-http-solver-d2tak`
hanging around in our cluster so the cluster won't downsize until these pods are destroyed.

A simple

```
kubectl get pods -A | grep cm-acme
```

will list all the pods that need to be destroyed with

```
kubectl delete pod -n {namespace} {pod name}
```